# Linux route cache seems to load outdated settings

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ip, mtu

On SLES 11 SP3 (Kernel 3.0.101-0.46) I see the following route behavior:

When I set a route specific MTU once via `ip route change ... mtu lock 1500`, everything works as expected (setting an MTU of 1500 on a dev configured with MTU 9000).
I then change the route back to the initial setting (either with `mtu lock 9000` or not setting mtu at all), do a `ip route flush cache`, verified the cache is cleared with `ip route show cache`.

When I then ping a host in the respective subnet, the old route setting with `mtu lock 1500` is being loaded in the cache, even though the cache has been cleared (as described before) and `ip route show` shows the updated route with mtu 9000.

I have also tried disabling PMTU discovery by setting `net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc = 1` in sysctl, but that doesn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that packets leaving the interface have the correct MTU? Are you sure some other device is not altering and fragmenting them?

Comment: Yes, checked with tcpdump that the packets are capped at 1500. This is true after I applied the initial rule as well as after I tried to change it back to 9000. There is just one switch inbetween the hosts that defaults to jumbo frames, so that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: AFAIK ip route flush cache only flushes learned routes and not static routes. Have you changed the MTU on both the hosts?

Comment: Yes, MTU has been changed on both hosts